# What does "/=" mean in Java?

Tags: java

I was checking some code online when i found the following statement

`number /= 10;`

I know that `/` mean divison and `=` is the assignment operator but i don't understand what it does in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is equivalent of  -

```
number = number / 10;
```

It is a composite operator - consist of division and assignment. You may found something like this -

```
+=
-=
%=  etc.
```

All of these above works similarly.

Answer (score 0):

It means that whatever the value number contains will be divided by 10 and the result will be stored back into number.

It is exactly equivalent to

```
number = number / 10
```

Most of the major operators have it:

```
number *= 10
number += 10
number -= 10
number %= 10
number >>= 10
number <<= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

It means

```
number =number/10;
```

Number divided by `10`

you can also do

```
 number operator=number
```

where operator can be `+`,`/`,`*`

Answer (score 0):

This is the shorter notation for `number = number / 10;`
The same exists for the other operators as well:

`x += y;` => `x = x + y;`
`x -= y;` => `x = x - y;`
`x *= y;` => `x = x * y;`
`x %= y;` => `x = x % y;`